# Handling NULL values in a CASE expression

Tags: sql-server

I found an error on one of my stored procedures when I used `CASE WHEN`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test 
    @a varchar(4) = NULL,
    @b  varchar(4) = NULL
AS
    UPDATE testtable
    SET a = CASE @a
               WHEN NULL THEN var1
               WHEN 'NULL' THEN NULL
               ELSE @a
            END,
    SET b = CASE @b
               WHEN NULL THEN b
               WHEN 'NULL' THEN NULL
               ELSE @b
            END
GO
```

What my goal is to update the said fields to NULL if I passed a variable string "NULL", and if I dont put parameters it will update nothing/set update to its own value, else, update the given value parameter.

This stored procedure fixed my `CASE`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test 
    @a varchar(4) = NULL,
    @b  varchar(4) = NULL
AS
    UPDATE testtable
    SET a = CASE 
              WHEN @a IS NULL THEN var1
              WHEN @a = 'NULL' THEN NULL
              ELSE @a
            END,
    SET b = CASE 
              WHEN @b IS NULL THEN b
              WHEN @b = 'NULL' THEN NULL
              ELSE @b
            END
GO
```

Why the latter worked and the former didn't?

Comment: Because the second one is checking "IS NULL" where the first one is an implicit "= NULL". Anytime you have any value and NULL in an equality it will always be NULL. Inside a case expression like your first one that condition will not evaluate to true because NULL <> true or false.

Comment: I get that, but is there a way to use the first format, I tried using IS NULL on that part but its a syntax error.

Comment: @Sid: the point is: if you need to check for `IS NULL` - you **cannot** use your style #1, because it always tries to check using regular equality and inequality operators, which **don't work** with `NULL`. If you have `NULL` , you must always use style #2.

Comment: got it, thanks, never thought this questionw would get a -1, i feel stupid :)

Comment: Not sure why it got downvoted or voted to be closed as being off topic. This seems to be very relevant not only topically but on SO.

Comment: Off topic but...I noticed you prefix your procedure with sp_, this is habit you should try to change. Prefixes in general seem silly to me but the sp_ prefix is reserved for system procedures. If MS releases a proc and there is a naming conflict, the system procedure will run instead of yours. It is also minutely slower if you don't specify the schema when executing because the engine will first search msdb.

Comment: @SeanLange hi, all my SP and the ancestors SP i use has sp_ prefix. But they are so unique and long that it wont provide(i think) a threat to conflict. But would this have a significant slowdown on execution? Thanks. --And maybe you could post your answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Because the second one is checking "IS NULL" where the first one is an implicit "= NULL". Anytime you have any value and NULL in an equality it will always be NULL. Inside a case expression like your first one that condition will not evaluate to true because NULL <> true or false.

---

Off topic but...I noticed you prefix your procedure with sp_, this is habit you should try to change. Prefixes in general seem silly to me but the sp_ prefix is reserved for system procedures. If MS releases a proc and there is a naming conflict, the system procedure will run instead of yours. It is also minutely slower if you don't specify the schema when executing because the engine will first search msdb. Here is a great article about the topic. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix